# How to change the amount of posts previewed on a page?

Tags: query, pre-get-posts

I have tried this code, but it doesn't work.

```php
function university_adjust_queries($query) {
    $query->set('post_per_page', '1');
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'university_adjust_queries');
```

Comment: You  can change  how many  posts appear on archives in the settings in WP Admin,  you don't  need a  filter for it

Answer (score 3):

You're missing an s.

`$query->set('posts_per_page', '1');`

However - you probably don't want to do this for every query, since that affects everything - widgets, back end, everything. You should make it conditional. For example:

```
<?php
function university_adjust_queries($query) {
    // If this is the main query, not in wp-admin, and this is the homepage
    if($query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() && $query->is_home()) {
        $query->set('posts_per_page', '1');
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'university_adjust_queries');
?>
```

This will make sure you're only affecting the main query (The Loop) on the homepage, and only on the front end. You can adjust the condition to target whichever spot you're wanting to affect.

Comment: good catch on the s, I didn't notice that at first :)

Comment: The missing s corrected that but also trying the version I posted in the question field  effected the back end posts in the admin area, as well. Thank you for fixes.

Comment: Could you please accept the answer if it solved everything? Then others searching for something similar can verify. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function university_adjust_queries($query) {
  if (!is_admin() AND is_post_type_archive('event') AND $query->is_main_query()) {
        $query->set('posts_per_page', 1);
}
```

Comment: Please edit your answer with details in how this resolves the issue.